# Customizing the Azure API Management developer portal

Tags: css, azure, azure-api-management

By viewing the markup for the templates that piece together the Azure API Management developer portal, you are able to provide inline styles to adjust the styling for elements.

Is there an existing stylesheet where I can store CSS classes that would then be used in each template view?

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create your own CSS file in the media library and then reference that from your templates.